# Finding simple shapes in 2D point clouds

Tags: image-processing, cloud, shapes, point

I am currently looking for a way to fit a simple shape (e.g. a T or an L shape) to a 2D point cloud. What I need as a result is the position and orientation of the shape.

I have been looking at a couple of approaches but most seem very complicated and involve building and learning a sample database first. As I am dealing with very simple shapes I was hoping that there might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Could you please mention the approaches that require training and data?

Answer (score 0):

By saying you don't want to do any training I am guessing that you mean you don't want to do any feature matching; feature matching is used to make good guesses about the pose (location and orientation) of the object in the image, and would be applicable along with RANSAC to your problem for guessing and verifying good hypotheses about object pose.

The *simplest* approach is template matching, but this may be too computationally complex (it depends on your use case). In template matching you simply loop over the possible locations of the object and its possible orientations and possible scales and check how well the template (a cloud that looks like an L or a T at that location and orientation and scale) matches (or you sample possible locations orientations and scales randomly). The checking of the template could be made fairly fast if your points are organised (or you organise them by e.g. converting them into pixels).

If this is too slow there are many methods for making template matching faster and I would recommend to you the *Generalised Hough Transform*. 
Here, before starting the search for templates you loop over the boundary of the shape you are looking for (T or L) and for each point on its boundary you look at the gradient direction and then the angle at that point between the gradient direction and the origin of the object template, and the distance to the origin. You add that to a table (Let us call it `Table A`) for each boundary point and you end up with a table that maps from gradient direction to the set of possible locations of the origin of the object. Now you set up a 2D voting space, which is really just a 2D array (let us call it `Table B`) where each pixel contains a number representing the number of votes for the object in that location. Then for each point in the target image (point cloud) you check the gradient and find the set of possible object locations as found in `Table A` corresponding to that gradient, and then add one vote for all the corresponding object locations in `Table B` (the Hough space).

This is a very terse explanation but knowing to look for Template Matching and Generalised Hough transform you will be able to find better explanations on the web. E.g. Look at the Wikipedia pages for Template Matching and Hough Transform.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to :

1- extract some features from the image inside which you are looking for the object.

2- extract another set of features in the image of the object

3- match the features (it is possible using methods like SIFT)

4- when you find a match apply RANSAC algorithm. it provides you with transformation matrix (including translation, rotation information).

for using SIFT start from [here](http://robwhess.github.io/opensift/). it is actually one of the best source-codes written for SIFT. It includes RANSAC algorithm and you do not need to implement it by yourself.

you can read about RANSAC [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways for detecting the shapes (L, T, ...) in your 2D pointcloud data would be using OpenCV or Point Cloud Library. I'll explain steps you may take for detecting those shapes in OpenCV. In order to do that, you can use the following 3 methods and the selection of the right method depends on the shape (Size, Area of the shape, ...):

- Hough Line Transformation
- Template Matching
- Finding Contours

The first step would be converting your point to a grayscale `Mat` object, by doing that you basically make an image of your 2D pointcloud data and so you can use other OpenCV functions. Then you may smooth the image in order to reduce the noises and the result would be somehow a blurry image which contains real edges, if your application does not need real-time processing, you can use `bilateralFilter`. You can find more information about smoothing [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html).
The next step would be choosing the method. If the shape is just some sort of orthogonal lines (such as L or T) you can use Hough Line Transformation in order to detect the lines and after detection, you can loop over the lines and calculate the `dot product` of the lines (since they are orthogonal the result should be 0). You can find more information about Hough Line Transformation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).
Another way would be detecting your shape using Template Matching. Basically, you should make a template of your shape (L or T) and use it in `matchTemplate` function. You should consider that the size of the template you want to use should be in the order of your image, otherwise you may resize your image. More information about the algorithm can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).
If the shapes include areas you can find contours of the shape using `findContours`, it will give you the number of polygons which are around your shape you want to detect. For instance, if your shape is `L`, it would have polygon which has roughly 6 lines. Also, you can use some other filters along with `findContours` such as calculating the area of the shape.